# React Native: There is an exception using react-native-fs

Tags: react-native, filesystems, expo

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Bk4.jpg]

This is an error when using React-native-fs. I am using expo to create my project without detach and tried not to detach as possible.  I want to read the content:// image retrieved from getPhotos in CameraRoll from react-native module as a file path. Is it because i have not detach my application. Is there a way to use expo to retrieve the file path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> You should link project
>
> react-native link react-native-fs
>
> or manual linking
>
> android/settings.gradle
> ...
> include ':react-native-fs'
> project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
> android/app/build.gradle
> ...
> dependencies {
>     ...
>     compile project(':react-native-fs')
> }
> ```
>
> add package .addPackage(new RNFSPackage())
>
> then generate new build